# Changing the background-color when panel open

Tags: html, css

I wanted to have a different background color when the panel is collapsed/open. Therefore, I have tried changing background-color in .collapse class but it changes the background color of different background. Kindly help on how I can change the background color when opened. Thanks

```
.collapse{
        background-color: yellow;
    }

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

      <div id="MainMenu">
        <div class="list-group panel">
          <a href="#demo3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 3</a>
          <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
            <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu1">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 1 a</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 2 b</a>
              <a href="#SubSubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Subitem 3 c <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <div class="collapse list-group-submenu list-group-submenu-1" id="SubSubMenu1">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Sub sub item 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Sub sub item 2</a>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 4 d</a>
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#demo4" class="list-group-item list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 4</a>
          <div class="collapse" id="demo4">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 1</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
           <a href="#demo5" class="list-group-item list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 5</a>
            <div class="collapse" id="demo5">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Subitem 1</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: wich background should be changed? on wich element.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You should look for which class is added when you collapse DOM is opened and you should nest the classes for adding that property. Suppose you want to change the color of 
`<div class="collapse">` and in your browser check when collapse division is opened which class is added to it. Suppose the division becomes `<div class="collapse active">`. then you should add properties for conjugated classes like

```
.collapse .active{
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Yes I did something like this. But it is changing different background. Here is the fiddle: https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/DglnYJTSKA

Comment: If you told me in which element you want background color change. Clickable parent  node  or expanded child nodes?